# How to pass in onChange with multiple diffrent value to pass in

Tags: reactjs

```
const {
    productName,
    contactNumber,
    milage,
    year,
    cc,
    city,
    state,
    price,
    brand,
    condition,
    description,
    image1,
    image2,
    image3,
    image4,
    image5,
} = formData;
```

```js
const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file);
  setUploading(true);
  
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/uploads/', formData, config);
    
    setFormData({ image1: data });
    
    // setFormData({ image1: data });
    setUploading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    setUploading(false);
  }
};
```

There are 4 more images have to upload how can i change image1 to use something like [e.target.name]?

my input field will be look like this that need to be change
currently works one image1 if i created another set of below code for image2 it crash the image1 field. how can i change the file upload image to use in Above code by using e.target.name to set as some thing like

setFormData({ image1: data });
setFormData({ e.target.name: data });

so that all the image can use the same uploadFileHandler

```
 <Form.Group controlId="image">
                                <Form.Label>Image 2</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Uploaded Address"
                                    name={image2}
                                    value={image2}
                                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                                    required
                                ></Form.Control>
                                <Form.File
                                    id="image-file"
                                    label="Choose File"
                                    custom
                                    onChange={uploadFileHandler}
                                ></Form.File>
                                {uploading && <Spinner />}
                            </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to pass name in your input field.

```
  <input
      type="file"
      defaultValue={field.files}
      onChange={(e) => setFormData({ e.target.name: e.target.files[0] })}
  />
```